# Spring Data REST - Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; Cannot schedule tasks after shutdown

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have a Spring Data REST project and I am getting this exception randomly when calling some endpoints.

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot schedule tasks after shutdown at
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431) at
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:377) at
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:461) at
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277) at
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) at
org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) at
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) at
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) at
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) at
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) at
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy165.findAll(Unknown Source) at
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor469.invoke(Unknown Source) at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) at
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) at
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) at
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy282.findAll(Unknown Source) at
org.springframework.data.repository.support.PagingAndSortingRepositoryInvoker.invokeFindAll(PagingAndSortingRepositoryInvoker.java:75) at
org.springframework.data.rest.core.support.UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory$UnwrappingRepositoryInvoker.invokeFindAll(UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory.java:204) at
org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResource(RepositoryEntityController.java:202) at
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor468.invoke(Unknown Source) at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) at
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) at
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) at
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:849) at
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:760) at
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) at
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) at
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) at
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) at
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) at
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) at
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) at
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at
org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at
org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.java:53) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at
org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.java:82) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at
org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:84) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at
org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:206) at
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:240) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at
org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111) at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) at
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) at
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at
org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.java:79) at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at
org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.java:82) at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at
org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:206) at
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:240) at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at
org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:84) at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) at
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) at
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at
org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at
org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at
org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) at
org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke(AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve.java:67) at
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) at
org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:181) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) at
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) at
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) at
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) at
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) at
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) at
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) at
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot schedule tasks after shutdown at
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SharedTimer.schedule(SharedTimer.java:100) at
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SharedTimer.schedule(SharedTimer.java:92) at
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:7568) at
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:866) at
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:768) at
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7194) at
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2930) at
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:248) at
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:223) at
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeQueryInternal(SQLServerStatement.java:700) at
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.isValid(SQLServerConnection.java:5583) at
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.isConnectionAlive(PoolBase.java:147) at
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:169) at
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:145) at
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:99) at
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) at
org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386) at
org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:87) at
org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:112) at
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:489) at
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor132.invoke(Unknown Source) at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216) at
org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:201) at
org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle.doGetConnection(HibernateJpaDialect.java:414) at
org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:177) at
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
... 147 more
```

Here is my db connection properties:

```
primary.datasource.jdbc-url=url
primary.datasource.username=username
primary.datasource.password=pass
primary.datasource.spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl=create
####
primary.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000
primary.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=600000
primary.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=1800000
###
primary.datasource.pool-size=30
primary.datasource.jpa.show-sql=true
primary.datasource.platform=local
primary.datasource.initialize=false
primary.h2.console.enabled=true
primary.h2.console.path=/h2-console
####
```

Here is my db config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "primaryEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "primaryTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"portal.api.repository"}
)
@Profile("!test")
public class PrimaryDbConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name = "primaryEntityManager")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean primaryEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("PrimaryDataSource");
        em.setDataSource(primaryDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(
                new String[]{"portal.api.model"});


        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter
                = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                env.getProperty("primary.datasource.spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                env.getProperty("primary.datasource.hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", "portal.api.config.CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy");
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("primary.datasource")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {


        return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "primaryDatasourceInitializer")
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "primary.datasource.spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl", havingValue = "create")
    public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer() {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("/import_local.sql"));

        DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(primaryDataSource());
        dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(resourceDatabasePopulator);
        return dataSourceInitializer;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "primaryTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager primaryTransactionManager() {

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
                primaryEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

I tried searching for similar questions but couldn't find any questions with this exact error message. So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please don't squash the stack trace onto a single unreadable line.

Comment: I tried formatting it several ways and it always comes as a single line. So any help in editing the question is appreciated

Comment: are you trying to connect two databases?

Comment: Yes. There are two databases for this application